# CFDocument PDFs are huge (ColdFusion 8)

Tags: coldfusion

I wanted to add a PDF generation button for articles. Everything is working well until I noticed that the file sizes are upwards of 4MB for a document with 200KB of JPG images and about 120KB of HTML. So, I tossed the CFDocument into the CFPDF tag which reduced it to 1.5MB. Better. Then I put it through Acrobat's web optimizer which took it down to 335KB. I cannot find an "optimizing" solution with either CFDocument or CFPDF. I was hoping for a quality setting or something. I should also note that CFDocument takes a while to process (relatively speaking). Since ColdFusion 9 added an optimize function, I'm guessing that I'm out of luck until this server is upgraded. True?

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" 
            localurl=true 
            name="loc.tempPDF">

    <cfoutput>#loc.articleContent#</cfoutput>

</cfdocument>

<cfpdf action = "write" 
       destination = "#expandPath('\pdf\temp.pdf')#" 
       source = "loc.tempPDF"  
       overwrite = "yes" 
       saveOption = "linear" />
```

Comment: report it to Adobe: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, there is currently no way to optimize PDFs in ColdFusion 8 with the native `cfdocument` or `cfpdf` tags. If you absolutely have to make this happen without upgrading to CF9 (which has much improved PDF compression), then you could look at the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library for generating PDFs via Java.

Comment: So, I loaded CF9 just to see the results. The dang file goes from 1.5MB with the simple cfpdf write to 8.5MB with cfpdf action=optimize. Whaaaaaaaaaaat?

Comment: Hey Jason. Check out the documentation on cfpdf in CF 9 (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html). There are a ton of options you can choose for how the optimization happens (downsampling, removing embedded fonts, etc, etc, etc). Play with the different options to see what exactly needs to be removed to get a decent size.

Comment: I realize this post is several years old but I'm curious if anyone has ever gotten the optimize function to do what it should. I've tried all the options, in pretty much any combi I can imagine and the best I get is the same size. Adding any of the algos basically doubles the file size (to around 50mb). Real bummer since the files should really only be 1mb or so given the content being loaded in. Very very annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I built a Document Management System using CF 6.1 a few years ago. I used [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) to create, concatenate and optimize PDFs.

[Here's a blog post](http://blog.rot13.org/2011/05/optimize-pdf-file-size-using-ghostscript.html) showing how you can use GS to optimize a PDF's size.

Comment: I found your blog post before I found this StackOverflow post.  Here's the BAT script I wrote to optimize a directory of 628 bloated ColdFusion-generated PDFs. The aggregate filesize went from 9.545 gb to 1.39gb (85% smaller!)  

    set PATH="c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.05\bin\";"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.05\lib\";"%PATH%"  

    FOR %%Z IN (*.pdf) DO gswin32 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOUTPUTFILE=d:\pdf_temp\%%Z %%Z